# como llamar un componente en cada step de un formulario

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

saludos programadores ayuden por favor: mi problemática es la siguiente tengo la tarea de crear un loader estoy usando Jquery, el problema resulta en que al recargar la pagina muestra la animación. Yo necesito que la muestre en cada step del formulario. Lo que necesito es que este muestre la animación mientras carga, al momento de hacer esto se pare, y que la muestre al avanzar o retroceder en las paginas de este formulario.

En resumen: tengo una animacion de un icono saltando como loader, este SOLO se muestra al inicio de la pagina principal y cuando actualizo los steps de las paginas de mi formulario. necesito que se muestre al avanzar o retroceder en las paginas.

[image: Codigo del metodo que uso, que solo muestra la animación al recargar la pagina (colocada en index.html)]

```
$(window).on("load", function () {
$(".loader-wrapper").fadeOut("slow")  })


<div class="loader-wrapper">
<img src="public-assets/iconosma.svg" class="ld ld-bounce" width="100px; </div>
```

Comment: Agrega el código _como texto, con formato_, con el botón que indica `{}`.

Comment: No alcanzo a comprender qué problema es el que tienes, creo que seria mejor si completas tu pregunta con un [mcve]. Un saludo.

Comment: porque agregaste vue, si no estas usando vue?

Comment: me habia equivocado de etiqueta